# Moving comment box on the webpage

Tags: php, html, comments

My question is rather simple. But I am seriously stack as I have never done moving commentary box and nor applying it before.

Here is the code of a comment box I got from a free source:

```
<form method='post'>
  <div class="name">NAME: <input type='text' name='name' id='name' /><br /></div>

  Comment:<br />
  <textarea name='comment' id='comment'></textarea><br />

  <input type='hidden' name='articleid' id='articleid' value='<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?>' />

  <input type='submit' value='Submit' />  
</form>
```

And now I am trying to position it so it fits nicely on my page. I managed to move it on the page by putting the whole piece of code in a div, but when it comes to Name and comment fields even I am not sure what to do. Would be great to see some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Bootstrap to make a clean design of your form.

Add [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) to your Head of your HTML page:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then you can modify your form code to use Bootstrap containers, form-groups and form-control classes to structure and style your code. See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) for more details. `form-group` group label's and input fields together removing the need to create custom css or use html breaks to change the structure of the page. `form-control` adds Bootstrap styling to the input fields.

I created an example from your code sample above using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Example Form</h1>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nameInput">Name</label> <input class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="commentInput">Comment</label> 
                <textarea class="form-control" id="commentInput"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input id='articleid' name='articleid' type='hidden' value='&lt;? echo $_GET["id"]; ?&gt;'>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

See code pen to view the form - http://codepen.io/jamesg1/pen/ALAZKg

Comment: Thank you James. It all works. I went on to the bootstrap link you have shared but couldn't find information related to positioning and styling for comment boxes. Do you know any other good source to read bout it?

Comment: @MaxVisna The example http://codepen.io/jamesg1/pen/ALAZKg styles all of the forms and input fields using bootstrap. It is positioned using bootstrap containers - you can read bootstrap docs - http://getbootstrap.com/. I would suggest learning some basic html and css concepts - http://www.w3schools.com/html/ so you can create a more concise question.